# found : spray.routing.Directive0 (which expands to) spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] required: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HList]

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, spray-client

I need help. I am trying to use CURL to do HTTP POST & use spray routing along with parameters

```
curl -v -o UAT.json "http://*****/pvdtest1/14-JUL-2014?enriched=true" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "text": "Test", "username": "User" }'
```

My JSON Post is optional, means I can also get request as

```
curl -v -o UAT.json "http://*****/pvdtest1/14-JUL-2014?enriched=true"
```

In the routing if I use

```
 path("pvdtest1" / Segment) { (cobDate) =>
          (parameters('enriched.as[Boolean] ? false) & post) {
            (enriched) => {
              println(" inside post")
              entity(as[Message]) { message =>
                println(" inside post 1")
                logger.debug("User '{}' has posted '{}'", message.username, message.text)
```

above code works file

but if I try to make POST optional, it does not work

```
 path("pvdtest1" / Segment) { (cobDate) =>
          (parameters('enriched.as[Boolean] ? false) | post) {
            (enriched) => {
              println(" inside post")
              entity(as[Message]) { message =>
                println(" inside post 1")
                logger.debug("User '{}' has posted '{}'", message.username, message.text)



Error:(166, 56) type mismatch;
 found   : spray.routing.Directive0
    (which expands to)  spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil]
 required: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HList]
Note: shapeless.HNil <: shapeless.HList, but class Directive is invariant in type L.
You may wish to define L as +L instead. (SLS 4.5)
          (parameters('enriched.as[Boolean] ? false) | post) {
```

Can someone please help in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `|` method in Spray requires that both sides are of the same kind. `parameters` provides one Boolean, `post` no value. The `&` method concats the two directives, so they may may be of different kinds.

You could change that line to the following to allow both get and post, and capture the *enriched* parameter:

`(get | post) { 
  (parameters('enriched.as[Boolean] ? false)`

Comment: No, `(post & provide(false))` makes no sense (though the rest of the explanation is correct). In spray, `post` and `get` are just filters which you don't have to provide at all. If you want to restrict an inner route to either `get` or `post` requests use `(get | post)`. See my answer at   https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spray-user/viCmnOZNi1s/vJTvWn0BSAMJ